# how to trigger b-overlay in a loop

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to show b-overlay inside a loop. i.e. there are multiple rows and each row is  having a button(trigger) with an overlay. The issue that I'm facing is that I don't see a way to trigger a overlay that is specific to a row when the relevant button is clicked. If I set showOverlay = true, it triggers all overlays at once.

Is there a way to achieve this? e.g. can I trigger the overlay using its id?

```
<template>
    <b-row
          v-for="(subOrder, index) in subOrders"
          :key="subOrder.subOrderId"
        >
        <b-overlay show:showOverlay rounded="sm">
            <b-col md=6>
                {{ subOrder.orderNumber }}
                 <b-button
                    size="lg"
                    variant="primary"
                    @click="onSubmit(subOrder.subOrderId)"
                  >
                    Submit
                  </b-button>
            </b-col>
        </b-overlay>
    </b-row>
</template>
<script>
    import { BRow, BCol, BButton, BOverlay,} from 'bootstrap-vue'  
    export default {
        components: {
            BRow,
            BCol,
            BButton,
            BOverlay,
        },  
        data() {
            return {
            showOverlay: false,
           }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit(id) {
                this.showOverlay = true;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should create a variable inside your array using a map like subOrders example `subOrders.map(s => ({...s, showOverlay : false}))`
and them in your  `<b-overlay show:subOrder.showOverlay rounded="sm">`
and in the buttom to toogle overlay =  `@click="subOrder.showOverlay = !subOrder.showOverlay"`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone storing showOverlay in the dataset. however, I used your concept to create a separate array and store relevant keys.  e.g. `subOrder.forEach(x => {
        showOverlayArray.value.push({ subOrderId: x.subOrderId, showOverlay: false })
      })` thank you!